# Filter array of objects by array of objects [TypeScript] [ES6]

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

How to filter array of objects by array of objects with conditions.

Interfaces:

```
interface Person {
    age: number;
    available: boolean;
}

interface PersonFilter {
    predicateFn(arg: Person): boolean;
}
```

Data:

```
const persons = [
  {
    "age": 2,
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "age": 5,
    "available": true
  }
];
```

Conditions to filter:

```
const filters = [
    {predicateFn: person => person.available},
    {predicateFn: people => person.age > 2}
];
```

How to filter this array of objects using current filters structure ?

```
function getFilteredPersons(filters): Person[]{
return persons.filter( ?? );
}
```

Expected output:

```
  [
      {
        "age": 5,
        "available": true
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it with the `Array.prototype.every` function, it would be something like:

```js
const persons = [{
    age: 2,
    available: false
  },
  {
    age: 5,
    available: true
  }
];

const filters = [{
    predicateFn: person => person.available
  },
  {
    predicateFn: person => person.age > 2
  }
];

function getFilteredPersons(filters) {
  return persons.filter(p => filters.every(filter => filter.predicateFn(p)));
}

console.log(getFilteredPersons(filters));
```

Comment: Works perfect! This is what I need, Thank you :)